# Fill Long Array with Range Values

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am trying to take the values of a range and put them into an array.  I have the following code which works great:

```
Dim rg As Range
Dim Inputs() As Variant
Set rg = ("A1:B10")
Inputs = rg
```

But when I try to use Long instead of Variant I get a Type Mismatch error, even though all of the values are numbers.  Is it possible to create a Long array instead of a Variant array?

Comment: Yes, but you have to pass them to the array 1 by 1. Like iterate each range then pass to the array.

Comment: If the cells contain numbers then the array contents are of `Double` and not `Long`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub RangeToLong()
Dim rng As Range
Dim mylong() As Long, i As Long

Set rng = Sheet3.Range("A1:A10")
ReDim mylong(rng.Cells.Count)
'Debug.Print LBound(mylong), UBound(mylong)
For i = LBound(mylong) To UBound(mylong)
    mylong(i) = rng(i)
    'Debug.Print mylong(i)
Next
End Sub
```

**Edit1:** For 2D Long Array

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub RangeToLong()
Dim rng As Range
Dim mylong() As Long, i As Long, j As Long

Set rng = Sheet3.Range("A1:B10")
ReDim mylong(1 To rng.Rows.Count, 1 To rng.Columns.Count)
'Debug.Print LBound(mylong), UBound(mylong)
For i = LBound(mylong, 1) To UBound(mylong, 1)
    For j = LBound(mylong, 2) To UBound(mylong, 2)
        mylong(i, j) = rng(i, j)
        'Debug.Print mylong(i, j)
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: To downvoter: Is my answer not useful? :) Sorry, I'm just wondrin.